# Работа с методами Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Делаю список линков, но никак не могу понять, как сделать метод для апдейта линка? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Link } from '../linksArr';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { LinkListService } from '../link-list.service';


export const LINKS: Link[] = [
  { titleL: 'habrahabr', link: 'https://habrahabr.ru/' },
  { titleL: 'facebook', link: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
  { titleL: 'w3school', link: 'https://www.w3schools.com' },
  { titleL: 'angular', link: 'https://angular.io/' },
  { titleL: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-links',
  template: `
  <linkaAdder-app (submit)="addLink($event)"></linkaAdder-app>
  <div>
    <ul class="links">
      <li class="linksli" *ngFor="let link of links"
        [class.selected]="link === selectedLink">
        <div class="title">
          <span class="badge">{{link.titleL}}</span> 
          <span>{{link.link}}</span>
        </div>
        <button (click)="likeItem(link)" class="btn like">Like</button>
        <button (click)="onSelect(link)" class="btn change">Change</button>
        <button (click)="removeItem(link)"class="btn del">X</button>
      </li>
      <linkaAdder-app *ngIf="editMode" [link]="selectedLink" (submit)="updateLink($event)"></linkaAdder-app>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./links.component.css']
})
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() linkItem: any;
  @Output() remove: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  editMode = false;
  constructor(private linkListService: LinkListService) { }
  link = LINKS;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = this.linkListService.getLinkList();
  }

  links = LINKS;
  selectedLink: Link;

  onSelect(link: Link): void {
    this.selectedLink = link;
    this.editMode = true
  }

  addLink(link: any) { 
    this.links = this.linkListService.addItem(link);
  }
  updateLink(event){
    console.log(this.linkItem);
    console.log(event);
    this.linkItem.replace(event);
    
    
    this.editMode = false;
  }
  removeItem(item) {
    this.links = this.linkListService.removeItem(item);
  }
  // likeItem(item) {
  //   item.style.background = "red";
  // }
}
```

Comment: так вроде уже есть метод `updateLink`

Comment: он не работает.

Comment: почему ты так думаешь? Что именно не работает? Метод не вызывает? Вызывается, но выдает ошибку? Вызывается, но с неожиданным результатом?

Comment: потому что видает ошибку с .replace

Comment: И какая именно ошибка?